# Why are checkboxes tiny in safari/chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

The page looks great in Firefox, but in Safari/Chrome the checkboxes are just tiny dots. I'm not a CSS guy, but I think this is causing it.

```
div#contact div#topics div.row input {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    position: relative;
    top: 3px;
    *overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me with that css http://jsfiddle.net/6hYgK/

Comment: Does your css have anything that looks like `-webkit-transform: scale(.2)` in it?

Comment: No. But if I put 12px for width and height it looks fine.

Comment: Without the `12px`, where does "Inspect Element" say the height for the checkbox is defined?